# Create Xml Elements dynamically in XSLT C#

Tags: c#, xslt, element

I want to create as many `<Group folder = "GroupName">` elements as they are in the Main xml dynamically using XSLT. Also, the `<Data>` element added as the last child should be added only once inside.

Main Xml

```
<Root>
    <ClassA>
    <Groups>
    <Group1>
        <Group2>
            <Group3>
             ............
            </Group3>
        </Group2>
    </Group1>
    </Groups>
    <Data>
        <Name>George</Name>
        <Class>A</Class>
    </Data>
    </ClassA> 
</Root>
```

I need an Xml like this

```
<Data>
    <ClassA>
    <Group folder = "Group1">
        <Group folder = "Group2">
            <Group folder = "Group3">
             ............

            <Data>
                <Name>George</Name>
                <Class>A</Class>
            </Data>
            </Group>
        </Group>
    </Group>

    </ClassA> 
</Data>
```

Comment: You should include your XML in the question body, as links can go stale.

Comment: XML transformations can be accomplished either via XSLT or C#.  In my experience there's not much point in using both -- unless you have an XSLT transform already written and you need to accomplish the same thing from within C# .

Comment: So you're asking for the Xslt or full C# code? Also please don't post images here but text.

Comment: Use text, not screenshots.

Comment: I have edited my post .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create elements dynamically in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522971/create-elements-dynamically-in-xslt)