# Create elements dynamically in XSLT

Tags: xslt, element

I want to create as many `<Group>` elements as they are in the Main xml dynamically using XSLT as `<Group folder ="Group1">` in the new Xml. Also, the `<Data>` element added as the last child should be added only once inside.

Main Xml

```
<Root>
    <ClassA>
    <Groups>
    <Group1>
        <Group2>
            <Group3>
             ............
            </Group3>
        </Group2>
    </Group1>
    </Groups>
    <Data>
        <Name>George</Name>
        <Class>A</Class>
    </Data>
    </ClassA> 
</Root>
```

I need an Xml like this

```
<Data>
    <ClassA>
    <Group folder = "Group1">
        <Group folder = "Group2">
            <Group folder = "Group3">
             ............

            <Data>
                <Name>George</Name>
                <Class>A</Class>
            </Data>
            </Group>
        </Group>
    </Group>

    </ClassA> 
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need the following templates:

1. Matching `Root`. Generate `<Data>` element and inside it
   apply templates to the whole own content.
2. Matching `ClassA`. Copy the own element and inside if
   apply templates to the content of the child `Groups` element.
3. Matching elements with name containing `Group` and then a digit.
   Create `Group` element with proper `folder` attribute.
   Apply templates to its content (if any).
   If this element does not contain any child element, copy
   `Data` element from ancestor `ClassA`.
4. The *identity template*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
     <Data><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Data> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ClassA">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="Groups/*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[matches(name(), 'Group\d')]">
    <xsl:element name='Group'>
      <xsl:attribute name="folder" select="name()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:if test="count(*) = 0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ClassA/Data"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWtw

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:element name="Data">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ClassA">
        <xsl:element name="ClassA">
            <group floder="{Groups/Group1/name()}">
                <group floder="{Groups/Group1/Group2/name()}">
                    <group floder="{Groups/Group1/Group2/Group3/name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Groups/Group1/Group2/Group3"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Data"/>
            </group>
                </group>
            </group>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Try if is benifial for you.